# How to display ALL fields in table without duplicate rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display ALL the fields for all entries in the table analysis which meet criteria in other tables, WITHOUT displaying any duplicate rows in analysis.

Because I want to show all the fields in analysis, I can't use DISTINCT. So I use wildcard with GROUP BY but the query returns fields not just in analysis. It's bringing in fields from personal and exam as well.

```
            SELECT *
            FROM analysis
            JOIN personal
            ON analysis.FirstName=personal.FirstName
            AND analysis.LastName=personal.LastName 
            JOIN exam 
            ON personal.P_ID=exam.P_ID
            WHERE exam.Level='B1'
            AND exam.Certification='Full'
            GROUP BY analysis.LastName
```

I can get what I want using DISTINCT and specifying EVERY field in analysis, but there are currently 13 fields, so I'd prefer some neater syntax than:

```
            SELECT DISTINCT analysis.LastName, analysis.FirstName, analysis.X, analysis.y, ETC ETC 
            FROM analysis
            JOIN personal
            ON analysis.FirstName=personal.FirstName
            AND analysis.LastName=personal.LastName 
            JOIN exam 
            ON personal.P_ID=exam.P_ID
            WHERE exam.Level='B1'
            AND exam.Certification='Full'
```

Comment: SELECT * .... GROUP BY analysis.LastName is bad understanding on how GROUP BY should work... https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: You should use the DISTINCT syntax to remove duplicates it's designed for that... GROUP BY is designed to work with aggregate functions like COUNT, MAX, MIN and MAX you dont use aggregate functions so you should not use GROUP BY to remove duplicates

Comment: Thanks, I'll avoid using GROUP BY there.

Comment: But GROUP BY removes duplicate rows. How do I remove duplicates without it?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT analysis.*
            FROM analysis
            JOIN personal
            ON analysis.FirstName=personal.FirstName
            AND analysis.LastName=personal.LastName 
            JOIN exam 
            ON personal.P_ID=exam.P_ID
            WHERE exam.Level='B1'
            AND exam.Certification='Full'
```

Try above code.
Hope this will helps.

Comment: That worked! I was SURE I'd tried that yesterday. I must have used table.* without using GROUP BY as well. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: @Hego Yes you can remove that group by.,i thought you had some business logic with it.

Comment: This answer should not be upvoted.This SQL is incorrect because it will give you bad results because not all fields off analysis is named within the GROUP BY....  SELECT analysis.* .... GROUP BY analysis.LastName is bad understanding on how GROUP BY should work...  read this https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Ok, and I read the article. Thanks. But GROUP BY removes duplicate rows. How do I remove duplicates without it?

Comment: @Hego `Select DISTINCT analysis.*  FROM ` try this one.

Comment: Thanks, Sagar. Have just seen this: will try at next opportunity and let you know!!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT analysis.* doesn't remove duplicates for me.

Comment: @Hego Please check with simple SELECT DISTINCT * from analysis.
It's not possible that `SELECT DISTINCT analysis.* ` gives duplicate entry.